# cannot convert from 'method group' to Func<List<ClassA>> when instantiating a new Task

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I have a function that returns a list i.e

```
public List<ApiClass> FuncA(List<DBClass> param)
{
  //returns list
  //however this list performs a lengthy operation that involves looping through the incoming parameter list
}
```

I would like to call the above method asynchronously as I try do so below:

```
public static async void CallingMethod()
{
   Task<List<ApiClass>> unitOfWork = new Task<List<ApiClass>>(FuncA); //I'm getting an error here when I pass in FuncA 
   unitOfWork.Start();
   List<ApiClass> getList = await unitOfWork;
}
```

I am getting an error here: `Task<List<ApiClass>> unitOfWork = new Task<List<ApiClass>>(FuncA);`

Comment: Can you do `await FuncA(myList)`?

Comment: Also, the new C# 8 `IAsyncEnumerable` class may come in handy here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2019/november/csharp-iterating-with-async-enumerables-in-csharp-8

Comment: You are missing the argument for the parameter `List<DBClass> param`.

Comment: Have you considered `Task.Run`?

Comment: @Silvermind It gives an error when I try add a parameter to FuncA in the Task Invocation

Comment: How can I amend the method when I change it to use Task.Run() instead? @mjwills

Comment: @rhughes I'm not following how you're suggesting I do this. At which point in the execution should I amend it to the way you suggest?

Comment: https://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/05/a-tour-of-task-part-1-constructors.html - `TL;DR: Do not use Task or Task<T> constructors.` Read that post, and the following posts in the series.

Comment: [Avoid async void](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming#avoid-async-void). It's for event handlers only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Task<List<ApiClass>>` requires method signature like this: `public List<ApiClass> FuncA()` - without any method parameters.

How does `Task` would know what parameters pass to `FuncA`?

You can try this:

```
List<DBClass> inputData = ...
Task<List<ApiClass>> unitOfWork = new Task<List<ApiClass>>(  () => FuncA( inputData )  );
```

It creates inline `Func<List<ApiClass>>` using lambda expression.

Comment: https://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/05/a-tour-of-task-part-1-constructors.html - `The use case for the task constructors is extremely small.`

Comment: I concur. It does not have a lot of overloaded arguments